# Invoke a SOAP web service method with simple parameters from browser using ONLY url

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

What controls if a web service method can be invoked from a browser via a URL or not?

The platform (among other things) on which the service is authored (java vs .net vs xxx)?

I know .net based web services provide a nice interface to invoke the methods.
Why does it not happen for java based ones?
Since in both cases it is soap, should they not behave identically?
What is .net implementation doing extra that java doesn't?
What are the necessary config settings/properties that control if a soap webservice is browser invokeable?
I have seen plenty of online examples where for simple arguments, the web service methods seem to be browser invokeable, via a URL.
But in my case, it doesn't seem to work.

I have a working web service (JAX-WS), wsdl as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!--  Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. 
--> 
<!--  Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. 
--> 
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://services/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://services/" name="MYServiceService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://services/" schemaLocation="http://example.com:8888/myservice?xsd=1" /> 
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getToken">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getToken" /> 
    </message>
    <message name="getTokenResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getTokenResponse" /> 
    </message>
    <portType name="MYService">
        <operation name="getToken">
            <input message="tns:getToken" /> 
            <output message="tns:getTokenResponse" /> 
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MYServicePortBinding" type="tns:MYService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" /> 
        <operation name="getToken">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" /> 
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" /> 
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" /> 
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="MYServiceService">
        <port name="MYServicePort" binding="tns:MYServicePortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://example.com:8888/myservice" /> 
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Works fine (if consumed via client app, I get the method output successfully).

But when I try using via browser, I get a `"No JAX-WS context information available"` message.

`http://example.com:8888/myservice?wsdl` works fine, but

`http://example.com:8888/myservice/getToken?param0=xxx&param1=yyy` gives me the above message. `param0,param1` are the same names I used in the implementation, and they are both of type `String`.

I am hosting the web service in a JRE 1.6 environment, as a stand alone Java program.

Comment: Your question is actually `How to call a jax-ws web service via http get`. The browser uses http get instead of http post, which jax-ws requires. If you used apache-cxf I think you could do what you want. Since they treat it somehow and then pass it to jax-ws, which they use internally. I don't know what .net does, but I believe something similar as cxf.